# Does eclipse support automatic replacement of dashes and other characters?

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Consider the following - well - very basic code snippet:

`int a = b – 2`

The minus symbol in the middle is actually not a minus (or "hyphen"), but a dash. The correct snippet would look like this:

`int a = b - 2` - the correct minus being slightly shorter.

So, I stumbled on this a lot of times already when copying code from some (online-)book or PDF to check it out in java. When writing the document the author probably didn't consider the word processor to replace the hyphens by dashes automatically.
With java this is not a big deal - "illegal character" - and I'm done. But when coding C/C++ using the CDT, this is actually not so easy to see. And the compiler errors are not very helpful either.

So: back to my question: Is there a way, a checker, a plug-in, something - that is able to replace such invalid characters **automatically** by any (configured) correct values? Specifically it would be great, if that would work together with CDT. Or how would you deal with that problem (if it were a problem to you)?

Thanks

Comment: look at notepad++ to do global search/replace on external files in batch.

Comment: Copy from text and paste to Notepad, then copy from Notepad and paste to Eclipse.

Comment: I already emphasized it: automatical!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only automatic solution, that prevents the use of dash instead of a hyphen symbol - and also other UTF symbols that are not permitted by most C compilers is: set the text file encoding to "US-ASCII". This can only be done for all files and languages in Eclipse however. But if accented characters or any other fancy arrows and dashes are not needed, this is a currently for me the best option to prevent inserting those characters by accident.

This can be done in **Window > Preferences > General > Workspace** and in the field `Text file encoding` set **Other > US-ASCII**.

Afterwards the dash character can still be inserted in the editor, but when saving eclipse will complain and one of the options is to select the first character, which is not of `US-ASCII` encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ctrl+f on eclipse and youll see two boxes, find: and Replace with, that should do the work.

Comment: Thanks - I know the basics of eclipse - the question is about "automatic" replacement. Like MS-Word does with the "-" when you type it, but the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse/Eclipse cdt does not have an automatic typo-correction. The only - very neat - automatic replacement that I'm aware of is the automatic replacement of . to -> for pointer types. I never type -> anymore.

See this option: **Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > Editor > Content Assist > Enable Auto-replace of '.' with '->' for pointer types**

Other than that: no. I couldn't find a plugin for this, either.